# Llamar a una funcion cada x segundos

Tags: c++, hilos

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de consola en VS2008. Tengo una funcion que tengo que llamarla cada 5 segundos, pero hasta que pasen esos 5 segundos el programa tiene que seguir corriendo. He probado a usar thread, pero no puedo incluirlo porque mi version de c++ es antigua. He tomado otro camino y consigo llamar a la funcion cada 5 segundos pero mientras el codigo no se ejecuta. Gracias de antemano.

```
void CALLBACK f(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime){cout <<"Hello";}

int _tmain(){
MSG msg;
SetTimer(NULL, 0, 100*60,(TIMERPROC) &f);
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
{
   TranslateMessage(&msg);
   DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
//mas codigo a ejecutar pero que no consigo...
return 0;}
```

Al final he conseguido solucionar el problema de este modo:

```
DWORD WINAPI solo_thread(void* arg){
int Counter = 0;
printf( "In second thread...\n" );

while ( true )
{
    if(Counter<10)
    {
        Counter++;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf( "Han pasado 10 segundos; Counter:-> %d\n", Counter );
        funcionalarm();
        Counter = 0;
    }

}

return 0;}

int _tmain(){
int x=0;
HANDLE hThread;
while (true)
{
    printf( "Creating second thread...\n" );
    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, solo_thread,NULL ,0, NULL);
    //WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle( hThread );
    while (x<10)
    {
        cout <<x;
        x=x+1;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    x=0;    
}

Sleep(6000);
return 0;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no puedes usar la librería `thread` entonces puedes optar por recurrir a alguna librería que te proporcione una implementación equivalente (por ejemplo Qt o boost) o bien puedes pegarte directamente con la API de Windows.

Yo te recomiendo la primera opción ya que programar sobre WinAPI suele acabar en constantes dolores de cabeza.

Un posible ejemplo con boost:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void thread()
{
  try
  {
    while( true )
    {
      funcionALlamarCada5Segundos();
      boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{5});
    }
  }

  catch( boost::thread_interrupted const& )
  { }
}

int main()
{
  boost::thread t{thread};

  // tu codigo aqui

  // Finalizamos el hilo
  t.interrupt();
  t.join();
}
```

Comment: Gracias eferion, tiene buena pinta el codigo. Antes habia probado con boost y me da varios errores. A que pueden deberse? 'Error 1 error C2039: 'localtime' : no es un miembro de 'std' C:\Users\P\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Timer 3\boost\date_time\c_time.hpp 101 Timer 3
'

Comment: @Andermutu la versión de VS que estás usando tiene casi 10 años, posiblemente no puedas usar la última librería de boost. Por otro lado puede que o bien te falten dependencias o que no hayas configurado la librería correctamente... es dificil darte una respuesta con tan poca información. Esto debería ser una pregunta independiente.

Comment: Si ya lo se, por desgracia es el unico entorno de desarrolo del qual dispongo. Gracias, revisare las dependencias.

Comment: @Andermutu ¿No tienes posibilidad de pasarte a mingw?

Comment: Tengo que utilizar visual studio 2008, ya que estoy desarrolando para Windows CE 7. No creo que mingw sea compatible.